# Matching ViewModel and View in MVVMCross

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-runtime, mvvmcross

I have an MVVM Cross application, and I'm trying to figure out why the initial screen isn't showing (this is on WinRT).

The following code looks like it loads the ViewModel `MainViewModel`:

```
var setup = new Setup(rootFrame);
setup.Initialize();

var start = Cirrious.CrossCore.Mvx.Resolve<Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxAppStart>();
start.Start();
```

However, the `Start` method of `MainViewModel` never gets called.  The reason appears to be this error in the output:

```
Error seen during navigation request to MainViewModel - error KeyNotFoundException: Could not find view for MyApp.PCL.ViewModels.MainViewModel
```

So, here's my guess as to the problem: it's looking for `MyApp.PCL.ViewModels.MainView`, Obviously, this doesn't exist.  The view is in: `MyApp.Views.MainView`.  Is my assumption correct and, if so, how can I persuade MVVMCross to look in the correct place?

EDIT:

The `Setup` method is called from the `MyApp.Windows` WinRT app.

```
protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
{
    return new MyApp.PCL.App();
}
```

MyApp.PCL is a portable class library that is referenced from `MyApp.Windows`.
`MyApp.PCL` contains the ViewModels, and `MyApp.Windows` contains the views.

I have tried to override `Start()`:

```
public class MainViewModel 
    : MvxViewModel
{

    public override void Start()
    {            
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        base.Start();
    }
```

but this never gets hit.

Comment: Shouldn't your view be in MyApp.WinRT.Views?

Comment: It would still be a different namespace?

Comment: By default Mvx WindowsStore looks for views in the entire assembly in which Setup is run. From your question, I've no idea wha's happening - can't see what your project/solution structure is. You could edit your question to provide more detail? Or I guess you could override https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/Platform/MvxSetup.cs#L304 to debug and step into what's happening in your case. There is some customisation info in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Customising-using-App-and-Setup#providing-additional-view-and-viewmodel-assemblies

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly Stuart.  I've updated my post.  One thing that I didn't mention (I don't believe it's relevant) is that the app is a universal app; however, I have removed the Windows Phone project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Massive Doh! here, but I'll post the solution; my view was not using the MvxStoreView, but the standard StoreView.

The solution was to change the view as follows:

```
 ...
 xmlns:views="using:Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsStore.Views"
 ...
<views:MvxStorePage
```